# IIS 7 Reliability and Performance monitor

Tags: iis

I am trying to figure out some of the categories I can monitor.  One of them, under the category of .NET CLR Remoting is Context Proxies.  Is Context Proxies literally how many proxies that are being used to connect to something such as a WCF service?

Answer (score 1):

What exactly you want to monitor? IIS is part of the system, so you can use general counters to monitor it (Process, Web Services and so on).

The Context Proxies you refer to should be .NET specific, not IIS specific.